# Vagrant provision sed command returns error

Tags: sed, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am trying to run a shell `sed` command as part of the `config.vm.provision`

```
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    systemctl stop firewalld
    systemctl disable firewalld
    swapoff -a
    sed -i '/\/swapfile/s/^/#/g' /etc/fstab
  SHELL
```

Basically what I want to do is comment the swap entry in the `/etc/fstab` file.

But I get an error :

```
    master: Running: inline script
    master: sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unterminated `s' command
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

The sed command runs perfectly fine when I run in on the box but errors out when I provide it as a part of my Vagrantfile.

Any idea why this might be ?

Comment: does it run without error if you replace `s/^/#/g` with `s/sw/sw/` ? If so, I'd guess `#` is being misparsed as a comment

Comment: If so, with some versions of sed, you can quote it as `\x23`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try?

```
$script = <<-SCRIPT
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl disable firewalld
swapoff -a
sed -i '/\/swapfile/s/^/#/g' /etc/fstab
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script
end
```